# Splitting string into parts with .replaceAll function from opposite direction? JAVA

Tags: java, string, replaceall

Let's say I have the following string in JAVA:

```
str = "B49FD7FD96B"
```

I can change this string into `B49F D7FD 96B` by doing the following:

```
str = str.replaceAll("....",  "$0 ");
```

**But how can I change my string into this???** `B49 FD7F D96B`

So in a way I actually need to use the function .ReplaceAll() from the opposite direction. Or is this not possible with .ReplaceAll() and do I need to use something else? If so, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: On what bases do you split the String? Is it based on the lenght (first 3 letters and then twice 4 letters?)?

Comment: If the input is always 11 characters I would just concatenate a few well-chosen substrings, but it is possible.

Comment: @Barry The bases on which I split is length, so I just want to split the string into parts of four characters.

Comment: @DavidConrad The input length differs, as the inputs are hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split it into groups of 4 with the leftovers at the beginning instead of the end by using `replaceAll` "the other way," you can just reverse the string, do it, and reverse it again:

```
str = "B49FD7FD96B";
str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
str = str.replaceAll("....",  "$0 ");
str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

Result: `"B49 FD7F D96B"`

Comment: Yess, this is the solution I need! But now when I see this, it seems as if this can be done much simpler without replaceAll. What would you suggest?

Comment: Since the input length differs you could use `str.length() % 4` to find the number of characters in the first section, if any, and then use a loop on the rest in groups of 4, but I'm not sure if that would be any simpler. It depends on what you mean by "simpler." It would be longer, but wouldn't use regular expressions.

Comment: @C.Snoeij You could also make this simpler by pulling out the string reverse into its own method: `String reverse(String s) { return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString(); }` and then this becomes `reverse(str).replaceAll("....", "$0 ").reverse()`.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason that you're using `replaceAll`? (It also seems like you're using a regular expression)
Why not simply use a for-loop to get your desired output?

If you want to use what you have you could try:

```
str = str.substring(0, 3) + " " + str.substring(3).replaceAll("....",  "$0 ");
```

Comment: No there is no reason why I need to use replaceAll. I'm new to Java so at first this seemed the easiest way but probably it isn't...

Answer (score 1):

This one is longer, but doesn't use a regular expression:

```
String groupInFours(String s) {
    int index = s.length() % 4;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (index > 0) {
        sb.append(s.substring(0, index));
    }
    for (; index < s.length(); index += 4) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(s.substring(index, index+4));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Create a StringBuilder and add any initial group of characters that is not a multiple of four, then add groups of four, prepended by spaces as necessary, for the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me this man!! I'll try this one out also!